# The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) XSSFCell, int Java(536871072)

Tags: java, if-statement, apache-poi

I want to compare two cell value, therefore, I added an if statement that helps me to compare it, here's the following code:

```
if (searchTheColumn != null && searchTheColumn2 != null) { // if that cell is present
                System.out.println(wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(rowNumber).getCell(10) + "\t" + wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(rowNumber).getCell(11));
                if (wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(rowNumber).getCell(10) || wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(rowNumber).getCell(11) > 300) // error here {

                }
                //int cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(searchTheColumn, formulaEvaluator); // get string cell value

        }
```

At the second if statement condition, I got an error that said `The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) XSSFCell, int`, I wonder how do I fix it? I tried to use the data formatter, but it seems like it does not support it.

Comment: because your getCell(par) is returning an object i assume, that's why you get the operator error. What exactly you are trying to control with that operator ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot compare an instance of an object to a number. You need the value of that `XSSFCell` in numerical form so that you can compare it.

Taking a quick look at [the docs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.html), `getNumericCellValue()` looks like it should do the trick. So use

```
wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(rowNumber).getCell(11).getNumericCellValue() > 300
```